# libav ffmpeg multiple streams performance issue

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I have a program capable of generating 5 mpeg transport streams simultaneously.  each stream has its own context and is done in an independent thread.  when only one stream is active everything works great.  as soon as i activate another stream my frame rate drops tremendously.  both streams still work properly just the frame rate is slow.  i have tracked it down to the call to av_interleaved_write_frame.  it goes from approx 4 ms when a single stream to over 50ms when two. i am running on a 6 core haswell-e with hyperthreading and the machine is nowhere near overoaded.

Comment: Did you check individual cpu core usage? One or more may may overloading..

Comment: yes,  none of the cores is pegged

Answer (score 1):

First test if running two separate processes of the same app, each app with one single stream, performance is good in both of the instances. If yes, I think it may be related to a multithreaded issue in your app. Please check if when you activate more than one stream in different threads, how these threads are synchronized. It may be a thread synchronization problem in your code.

Comment: there is no synchronization between the threads they are totally independent.  running two separates copies of this app is problematic.  perhaps i can reduce to a simpler test case